# How to verify for how long a user have been liking a page?

Tags: facebook, datetime, facebook-like, timestamp

I'm looking for the possibility to know fo how long a FB user have been liking a particular page.

I work in advertising, and we would like to offer FB users some items every week (for example, and the value would increase each week) if they like the page. Example, if somebody unlike the page, he would restart from the first item.

Do you ever figurate how to do this ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not. Facebook no longer allows to get a list of IDs for your page fans.

See this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/147185208750426 and Facebook respons: "Sorry, but there is no way to get the entire list of the people who have liked a Page. This is by design."

Comment: Crap...
Ok, i will have to find something else to sell our inventory then... thanks !